# Move image up towards the header in the sidebar

Tags: html, css

I would like to move the circular image of myself located in the sidebar up and in line with my name displayed in the header. The `contact` and `tech skills` sections might need adjusting as well.

I have learned about `absolute` versus `relative` and how it relates to this, but I just can't implement a working solution.

This  is what I have been working with:

```
<div style="position:relative; height:60px;">
<img src="profile_pic_circular.png"
   style="position:absolute; top:-10px; left:-30px; width:80px; height:80px; border:none;"
   alt="profile"
   title="profile photo" />
</div>
```

[Link to my resume with picture](https://iamericfletcher.github.io/distill_blog/cv.html).

Code:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Playfair+Display&display=swap");

/* Main text is monserrat*/
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3;
  color: #444;
}

/* Give headers playfair font */
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  color: #000;
}

/* When in PDF export mode make sure superscripts are nice and small and italic */
sup {
  font-size: 0.45rem;
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Avoid the breaking within a section */
.blocks {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

* {
  /* Override default right margin for sidebar*/
  --pagedjs-margin-right: 0.2in;
  --pagedjs-margin-left: 0.2in;
}

/* Customize some of the sizing variables */
:root {
  --sidebar-width: 12rem; /* Shrink sidebar width  */
  --sidebar-background-color: #f7fbff; /* Make sidebar blue */
  --sidebar-horizontal-padding: 0.01in; /* Reduce sidebar padding */
  --decorator-outer-dim: 10px; /* Make position deliniating circles larger */
  --decorator-border: 2px solid #bdd7e7; /* Make timeline a blue as well*/
}

.details .place {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.main-block:not(.concise) .details div {
  padding-top: 0.009rem;
}

/* Laptop icon isn't centered by default which is lame */
.fa-laptop {
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* When we have links at bottom in a list make sure they actually are numbered */
#links li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

/* Dont put the little fake list point in front of links */
.aside li::before {
  display: none;
}

/* Move closer to start and up towards header */
.aside ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.aside li::before {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -4.25pt;
  content: "• ";
}

/* Make sure elements in asside are centered and have a nice small text */
.aside {
  width: calc(var(--sidebar-width) + 9px);
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

/* Make little circle outline be a light blue */
.decorator::after {
  background-color: #08306b;
}

/* Remove the fake bullets from lists */
.aside li::before {
  content: auto;
}

.skill-bar {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.25rem;
  margin-top: 3px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* When the class no-timeline is added we remove the after psuedo element from the header... */

/* Removes the psuedo element on h2 tags for this section */
.section.no-timeline h2::after {
  content: none;
}

/* Without adding padding the content is all up on the title */
.section.no-timeline h2 {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Add styles for little cards  */
.info-card{
  width: 220px;    
  float: left;    
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected the sidebar (right-click, choose Inspect) and saw that `.aside` had a padding. Remove it to align your picture with your headline.

```
padding: 0.6in var(--sidebar-horizontal-padding)
```